# Can't authenticate iOS app with Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, api, appcelerator, sharekit

Hopefully someone can help here, it's incredibly frustrating!

I have a couple of iOS apps built using Appcelerator Titanium and using the latest Sharekit module to allow me to share content via Twitter & Facebook.

The Twitter module works fine, but I'm having issues with Facebook authentication.

Now, I don't think it's an issue with my code in Titanium as I'm using the 'exact' same code in a different app which works and posts fine.

These 2 apps in question I'm struggling with are newly added to Facebook's App portal, where as the 2 that are working are ones I've added many months ago.

I've tried to copy the settings on the working one with the incorrect one, but no luck.

On the device, when you tap 'Share with Facebook' it opens up the Facebook app, asks me to authenticate my app, then slides the view away leaves me inside the Facebook app and doesn't redirect me back to my native app.

In the simulator, it takes me to Safari to authenticate and then once I click accept it then throws a 'Page Can't be found' error.

it's almost like it can't work out the callback URL.

Anyone else got a suggestion? I'm pretty sure it's something i've not setup correctly on the Facebook side.

Simon

Comment: have you added the fb app id to your info-plist as a URL scheme?

Comment: @Martin Yeah I've done this, it's identical to the apps that do work for me. Makes me think that Facebook have altered something in the way you register a new native iOS app.

Comment: Did you try swapping the Facebook Application ID in your non-working project with a confirmed-working Facebook Application ID?

Comment: @Martin It was a plist issue in the end, I'd left an old version which was overwriting the new one every time the app was being built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to my plist file not being updated. I had copied it from the build folder originally into my project Resource folder, so the app was overwriting the new plist with that every time.

All sorted now!